# AWS database low Insert/s count

Tags: innodb, insert, aws

I just started getting into AWS and until now I used my computer as a DB instance(both SSD and Ramdisk).
On my computer I get 4.000 to 10.000 inserts/sec of random generated data.

I modified the same program(20 threads each up to 50.000 random inserts) to connect to a db.t2.micro instance (1 vCPU, 1GB ram, 20 GB SSD), I got ~80 inserts/sec max.

I switched to a db.r3.4xlarge (16 vCPU, 122GB ram, -unknown storage) and still could barely get up to 150 inserts/sec max.

Should I add more threads to my application or is this linked to write latency( currently 1ms)?

Any ideas on how could I improve insert speed?

Thank you!